# How to get the resource id of a drawable given to an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I need to get the id of the drawable I assigned to an ImageView by xml.

I have different buttons that need to change look when pressed, so I wanted to write just one method for all of them putting into 2 arrays the `NOT_TOUCHED` drawable ids and the `TOUCHED` drawable ids and so on...

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't.  You can get the Drawable itself, but not its id-  because it doesn't have to have an id (you can make a drawable at runtime too).  You could probably figure it out with some work, but its probably not the right thing to do.  Why do you want it, so we can figure out what you actually should do?

Comment: I have different buttons that need to change look when pressed, so I wanted to write just one method for all of them putting into 2 arrays the NOT_TOUCHED drawable ids and the TOUCHED drawable  ids and so on...

Comment: Use the ids of the buttons instead.  Or references to the buttons.  I'm still not totally clear on what you're doing, but the drawable's id probably isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the image view to different state when image view touch or not touch, you better use drawable selector resource. Create a drawable/background.xml like following, then set as background of your image view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/focused_image" android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_image"></item>

</selector>
```